# Package supervisor on Ubuntu 16.04 is missing

Tags: apt, software-installation, supervisor

After reading that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34272628/symfony-should-i-add-the-rabbitmqconsumer-command-to-crontab) I realise I need to install `supervisor`.

`sudo apt-get install supervisor` tells me:

```
E: Unable to locate package supervisor
```

`sudo apt-cache search supervisor` gives nothing.

Also when I look at other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551851/supervisor-doesnt-start-on-startup-on-ubuntu-16-04) it seems that it is installed by default in Ubuntu 16.04.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Why can't I find this package? How can I install it?

I also looked at [install recommendation on official doc of supervisor](http://supervisord.org/installing.html) but I would prefer to use the distribution package solution.

Comment: Are you running from a LiveUSB? `universe` should be enabled on an installed system.

Comment: @Pilot6 no LiveUSB, it is on a remote server and I have no GUI active on my ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at [the package in the 16.04 repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/supervisor), it seems that it is in the "Universe" repository.

So, you first need to enable it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then you can actually install the package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

Comment: thanks for your input @Android Dev but I've hit another wall: the `add-apt-repository universe` creates `/etc/apt/sources.list` that contains a single lign: `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe`. And the command `add-apt-repository universe`  returns: `WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'` + `'universe' distribution component enabled for all sources.`. `apt-get install supervisor` does not work after `apt-get update`. I look to understand the difference between /etc/apt/source.list and /etc/apt/source.list.d and it does not seems that it could be an issue.

Comment: Something is wrong with the installation. `/etc/apt/sources.list` should be there. It seems that it is some customized installation with some restrictions.

Comment: I had another issue linked to disk occupation. I fixed that and the answer provided works.